# ORA-01461: Does SUBSTR() return a LONG if the input string is > 4000 characters?

Tags: oracle, type-conversion, oracle12c

I have a NoteDetail table with a varchar(4000) field for NoteText and number(4,0) for NoteNumber. The idea is that if a note longer than 4000 characters comes in it's broken into multiple notes with incremented NoteNumber entries.

The logic for doing the inserts is below and it worked beautifully on Oracle 10. Recently the app was moved to Oracle 12c and I'm getting the error: "ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column"  The Oracle DBA can't figure out why this is happening.

Below is the essence of what my insert code is; my best guess is that if the incoming string is long enough then the SUBSTR() function returns a long even when I'm assigning to a variable of the type varchar2(4000).  For reference: Oracle SQL Developer indicates the error is happening at the point of the insert (in the loop of the else block below).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
DECLARE
  s_incoming_string  varchar2(32000);
  s_substring_value  varchar2(4000);
  i_note_iteration   number(4,0);
  i_note_iterations  number(4,0);
  i_substr_start     number(6,0);
  k_NoteId           number(19,0);
BEGIN
  SELECT noteid_seq.nextval INTO k_NoteId FROM dual;
  s_incoming_string := {a 7000 character long note};
  i_note_iterations := ceil(length(s_incoming_string)/4000);

  IF i_note_iteration = i_note_iterations THEN
    --I NEVER GET AN ERROR ON THIS BRANCH!!!
    INSERT INTO NoteDetail (NoteId, NoteNumber, NoteText)
    VALUES (k_NoteId, 1, s_incoming_string);
  ELSE
    FOR i_note_iteration IN 1..i_note_iterations
    LOOP
          i_substr_start := (4000 * (i_note_iteration - 1)) + 1;
                IF i_note_iteration = i_note_iterations THEN
                    --this is the last chunk of text; no need 
                    --to read past the end of the buffer
                  s_substring_value = SUBSTR(s_incoming_string, i_substr_start);
                ELSE
                  --I ONLY GET AN ERROR if this branch is executed before the insert:
                  s_substring_value = SUBSTR(s_incoming_string, 4000);
                END IF;

      INSERT INTO NoteDetail (NoteId, NoteNumber, NoteText)
      VALUES (k_NoteId, i_note_iteration, s_incoming_string);
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
```

Table schema is:

```
    DCLARE TABLE NoteDetail (
      NoteId      number(19,0),
      NoteNumber  number(4,0),
      NoteText    varchar2(4000)
    );
```

Comment: Please include the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. Please also append a structure ot the table. For now there are only your comments instead of real code and `insert` statements.

Comment: I added the schema and more code.

Comment: For folks voting to close this, would you at least explain why? I am only now encountering Oracle for the first time in my career and I have to make these samples so generic so I don't get fired for leaking company info. Please give me a break here.

Comment: The way you are doing this looks a bit artisan (Ie: Before the invention of the CLOB, somewhat 1980s): Why not use CLOB instead?

Comment: It's an old database and I'm not at liberty to make schema changes. This code is part of a .NET application that gives a very narrow, limited view into a retired Java application's database, and there are legal reasons that we have to be able to add notes and make limited updates.

Comment: Please run this query `select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter like '%SET%'` and append it's result to the question. This query examines NLS settings of your RDBMS. It would be nice if you executed this query on your Oracle 10 instalation too. Thank, you.

Comment: On Oracle 12c:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fme5t8q2s5usicu/query-result.png?dl=0

NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET  AL32UTF8

I'll run this on Orcale 10 in a sec.

Comment: On the Oracle 10g database both NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET and  NLS_CHARACTERSET have a value of "UTF8"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to ask about `select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS' ;`. If this query returns `BYTE` (default), then VARCHAR2 max length in bytes is 4000 bytes, and any string that contains multilingual characters and is 4000 characters long simply doesn't fit into `varchar2(4000 byte)` variable.

Comment: On both 10g and 12c it's showing "BYTE" -- which is odd because I would think it should fail in both locations.  I tried doing a CAST(SUBSTR(blah) AS VARCHAR2) on the branch where I'm taking 4000 character chunks for insertion but kept getting a different error: "PLS-00382 expression is of wrong type"

Comment: try using SUBSTRB and LENGTHB functions, if your text column is 4000 Bytes max.  Would have to be careful piecing it back too

Comment: Using SUBSTRB worked... and now my conflict is wanting to know WHY it works so I can understand this versus getting this hotfix into production so I can move on to the next task on fire. @tbone: please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using SUBSTRB and LENGTHB functions, if your text column is 4000 Bytes max. You would have to be careful piecing it back too.

Basically it comes down to multi byte character encoding.  If you are using [utf8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and your text contains multibyte characters, then 4000 chars is more than 4000 bytes (which is the max in your table column).  You can do as krokodilko suggests and change that to 4000 char, or split the data into 4000 byte chunks (which is what the substrb and lengthb functions do).

Note that you may have an issue with a multibyte char at the very end of the 4000 byte chunk if your cutoff is exactly 4000 bytes, depending on how you want to display the data.  If you piece the chunks back together first it should be fine, but test this fencepost case to be sure.  I'll do a quick test myself tomorrow.

Comment: When I started doing dbms_output.put_line() comparisons of LENGTH() and LENGTHB() it became immediately obvious what was going on. And now I see there is also a LENGTH4() function as well... at least I'm aware now of the multiplicity of charset types that exist and can affect my code. There is NONE of this complexity in SQL Server: just varchar for simple ASCII text and nvarchar for unicode.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer to your question, but rather some experiment I want to show to You.
My Oracle 12c installation has the same settings as yours:

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
WHERE parameter = 'NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS'
   OR  parameter like '%SET%'

PARAMETER                  VALUE        
-------------------------- ------------
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET     AL16UTF16    
NLS_CHARACTERSET           AL32UTF8   
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS       BYTE
```

And now examine this code:

```
DECLARE
   s_incoming_string  varchar2(32000);
   s_substring_value  varchar2( 4000 );
BEGIN
   LOOP
      s_incoming_string := s_incoming_string || 'żaba';
      exit when length( s_incoming_string ) > 4500;
   END LOOP;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Length in characters = ' || length( s_incoming_string ) );
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Length in bytes = ' || lengthb( s_incoming_string ) );

   s_substring_value := substr( s_incoming_string, 1, 4000 );

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Length in characters = ' || length( s_substring_value ) );
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Length in bytes = ' || lengthb( s_substring_value ) );
END;
/
```

If I run the above code, I get the following output:

```
Length in characters = 4504
Length in bytes = 5630

Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 12
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

---

Now If I change a declaraion of `s_substring_value` to `varchar2( 4000 char );` the code works without any error and it gives the following result:

```
DECLARE
   s_incoming_string  varchar2(32000);
   s_substring_value  varchar2( 4000 char );
BEGIN
   LOOP
      s_incoming_string := s_incoming_string || 'żaba';
      exit when length( s_incoming_string ) > 4500;
   END LOOP;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Length in characters = ' || length( s_incoming_string ) );
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Length in bytes = ' || lengthb( s_incoming_string ) );

   s_substring_value := substr( s_incoming_string, 1, 4000 );

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Length in characters = ' || length( s_substring_value ) );
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Length in bytes = ' || lengthb( s_substring_value ) );

END;
/

Length in characters = 4504
Length in bytes = 5630
Length in characters = 4000
Length in bytes = 5000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

More on this issue you can find here: [NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTIC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams127.htm#REFRN10124)

---

Note: polish character `ż` is encoded as two bytes in UTF8;

```
select dump('ż') as x from dual;
X                    
---------------------
Typ=96 Len=2: 197,188
```

so the string: `żaba` (in english: frog) takes 5 bytes, not 4.

---

Note 2: you need also to alter a table definition:

```
ALTER TABLE NoteDetail 
MODIFY  NoteText    varchar2(4000 char);
```